# Почему 0x07c0 * 16 в AX ? не понятно ? в коде же не умножается в 16

Tags: ассемблер

Читаю хаб -> https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/536132/
и все было по чуть-чуть понятно пока не дошел до этого...

```
movw $0x07c0, %ax
movw %ax    , %ds
movw (0x0A) , %ax
```

Здесь происходит:

1. загрузка значения 0x07c0 * 16 в AX;
2. загрузка содержимого AX в DS;
3. установка 0x7c00 + 0x0a в AX;

Почему умножается 16 на начальный (0x07c0) адрес ?

Comment: Автор имеет в виду длину регистра 16 бит, а не умножение на 16.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.